# issue in display of html content stored in database in java

Tags: javascript, java

Here i am trying to display html content stored in database.When i try it to display in js it gives me "Uncaught ReferenceError: VAR_1 is not defined" in console.

Database:

```
<div id="dashboard-greeting" class="museo">
    <div class="dashboard-greeting-instructions"> 
        <span>Track Progress</span>
        <div class="dashboard-greeting-counter round">
            <div class="dashboard-counter-label">Courses Completed</div>
            <div class="dashboard-counter-value">VAR_1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dashboard-greeting-counter round">
            <div class="dashboard-counter-label">Courses Needed</div>
            <div id="subNeeded" class="dashboard-counter-value"></div>
            <script> 
                var subNeedVar = VAR_2 - VAR_1;
                $("#subNeeded").html(subNeedVar);
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

.js

```
<div class="tool-button-container">
                    <input type="submit" name="View" value="LookUp" id="campaignSubmit" class="buOrange large"  onClick="validateConfigValues('configKeyName');"/>      </div>


function validateConfigValues(id1){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/adminConfigTest',
                data: ({configKeyName:configKeyName, clientId :clientId ,batchId : batchId, languageId : languageId}),
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                var deleteCachingBtn = $('<br><div id="deleteBtn"><Button id="deleteCaching" name="deleteCaching" class="buOrange large" onClick=deleteFromCaching(\'' + configKeyName + '\')> Remove from Cache </div>');
                var displayStringAppData = "";
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                $.each(obj, function(index,value) { 
                    displayStringAppData = displayStringAppData+"<br>"+value+"<br>";
                    alert("displayStringAppData"+displayStringAppData);
                });
                $("#dbModelWindow").html(displayStringAppData);
                if(~data.indexOf("Config is not found in DB also.")) {

                } else {

                    $("#dbModelWindow").append(deleteCachingBtn);
                }
                $('#dbModelWindow').modal({

                        "escClose": true,
                        "overlayClose": true,
                        "onShow": function() { $.modal.setContainerDimensions();},

                    });

                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
                    alert("Error occured. Please try after some time.");
                }
            });
    }
}
```

.java

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/adminConfigTest", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#adminConfigTest,'ADMIN_TEXT_CONFIG')")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getAdminConfigTestPost(HttpServletRequest request) throws  Exception {
        String configKeyName  = request.getParameter("configKeyName");
        String clientId = request.getParameter("clientId");
        String batchId = request.getParameter("batchId");
        String language = request.getParameter("languageId");
        List<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
            Number languageId = null;
            if(StringUtils.isBlank(language)){
                languageId = RCConstants.ENGLISH_LANGUAGE_ID;
            } else {
                languageId = Long.parseLong(language);
            }
            if(StringUtils.isBlank(clientId)){

                configManager.getConfigValue(configKeyName, null, "", false, true, languageId, arrList);
            }
            if(!StringUtils.isBlank(clientId) && StringUtils.isBlank(batchId)){

                configManager.getConfigValue(configKeyName, Long.parseLong(clientId), "", false, true, languageId, arrList);
            }
            if(!StringUtils.isBlank(batchId)){

                configManager.getConfigValue(configKeyName, Long.parseLong(batchId), languageId, arrList);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e ,e);
            throw e;
        }
        return JSONSerializer.toJSON(arrList).toString();
    }



  public  String getConfigValue(String configKey, Number batchId, Number languageId, List<String> arrList)throws Exception{
        if(arrList != null){
            arrList.add("Get config value for : "+ configKey);
            arrList.add("batch Id : "+ batchId);
            arrList.add("Language : "+ StringUtils.getLanguageCode(languageId));
        }
        try{
    String configKeyValue = null;
            String localConfigKeyWithBatchId = batchId+"-"+configKey+"-"+StringUtils.getLanguageCode(languageId);

String queryString = "from Config as model where model.configKeyName = ? and model.batchMetaDataId = ? and model.languageId = ? and model.isDeleted = 0" ;
                List<Config> configList = getHibernateTemplate().find(queryString, configKey , batchId ,languageId);


            if(!configList.isEmpty()) {
                    for (Config config : configList) {
                        configKeyValue = config.getConfigKeyValue();
                    }

                    CacheUtil.put(RCConstants.LOCAL_CACHE_WITH_BATCH,localConfigKeyWithBatchId, configKeyValue);
                    logger.debug("Returning value  from db  :  "+configKey+" - "+configKeyValue);
                    if(arrList != null){
                        arrList.add("Db: returning batch and language specific value : " + configKeyValue );
                    }
                }
return configKeyValue;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error(re, re);
            throw re;
        }
}
```

CacheUtil.java

```
       public static Cache localEhCache = null;
public static Cache localEhCacheWithBatchId = null;
  public static void put(int cacheNumber, Object key, Object value) {
        if (cacheNumber == RCConstants.LOCAL_CACHE) {
            localEhCache.put(new Element(key, value));
        } else if (cacheNumber == RCConstants.LOCAL_CACHE_WITH_BATCH) {
            localEhCacheWithBatchId.put(new Element(key, value));
        }
    }
```

But if i rewrite VAR_1 again by erasing VAR_1. It wont show this error.

I googled about this topic but didn't find any solution.
Please help me or suggest me what is going wrong here.

Comment: Please Format your code

Comment: Are you sure this is java related, and not only javascript?

Comment: yes,data fetching is done in java and display is done through javascript

Comment: Neither VAR_2 nor VAR_1 are anywhere declared in your example, please add the script where you define the vars.

Comment: Please also add the java part related to your question.

Comment: @JohannisK Please check updated code

Comment: Okay... I assume alert("displayStringAppData"+displayStringAppData); displays something from the JSON. Can you verify this displays the correct data?

Comment: @JohannisK yes that displays data in alert, but view of it is not displayed.

Comment: Then your question is not java related, only javascript, which is not my specialty. Do you have "var VAR_2" anywhere in your code? Also, that is the value of displayStringAppData ?